# Doppler effect for a driver of an ambulance

Tags: acoustics, velocity, doppler-effect

Im thinking about Doppler effect more than I should, because it makes me crazy now. Anyway, here is the question.

Does a driver of an ambulance hear a lower frequency of his horn, than it actually has?

I know that he and the horn is in the state of rest, but the air which transmits the sound waves could be viewed as in motion according to the driver and the horn. So I realized that he should hear lower frequency, because he is driving away from emited waves.

Am I right?

Thank you.

Comment: We never think about a physical phenomenon more than we should 

Comment: You could experiment with this yourself.   In a parked car with the window down so you can hear the horn... blow the horn.    Then while driving, blow the horn... Do they sound the same?